# Why is the double quotient $B\backslash G /B$ the same as $G\backslash (G/B \times G/B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, lie-groups

Why is the double quotient  $B\backslash G /B$ the same as $G\backslash (G/B \times G/B)$?

The particulars don't matter, as I'm really just trying to understand this on a set level. That being said, $G$ is a Lie group and $B$ is a Borel subgroup.

For a little context, i'm currently learning about the Bruhat decomposition. See Emerton's post here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15438/a-slick-proof-of-the-bruhat-decomposition-for-gl-nk/15554#15554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G$ acts on the set $S=G/B \times G/B$ through $$g.(aB,cB)=(gaB,gcB)$$

Let $$T=B/B\times G/B \subset S$$ We have a bijection $$G\setminus S \to B\setminus T\to B\backslash G /B$$ given by $$G.(aB,cB)=G.(B,a^{-1}cB)\to B.(B,a^{-1}cB)\to Ba^{-1}cB$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by $G.(aB,cB)=G.(B,a^{-1}cB)$. How do we "sneak a multiplication by $a^{-1}$" in between the action of $G$ and the element of $S$?

Indeed, this equality is troubling me.



Also, since you are exhibiting a bijection, could all your arrows $\rightarrow$ become $\iff$   ??

Comment: $G.(aB,cB)$ is an element of $G\setminus S$ (that is $S$ quotiented by the equivalence relation given by the action of $G$) it is the subset $\{ (eB,fB),\exists g\in G, e=ga,f=gc)\}$ of $S$, it is clearly the same as $G.(B,a^{-1}cB)$

Comment: Did you mean to say that $G.(aB,cB)$ is a *subset* of $G \backslash S$?

Comment: No, each element of $G\setminus S$ is a subset of $S$. In the same way that each element of $\Bbb{Z/nZ}$ is a subset of $\Bbb{Z}$ (of the form $a+n\Bbb{Z}$)

Comment: Sorry, i'm a little slow. Each arrow is a bijection?? Can you explain the first arrow to me??

Comment: Each of them. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hmm, seems mysterious to me that the orbit of $G$ on the tuple $(B,a^{-1}cB)$ are the same as the orbits of $B$ acting on it.

Comment: We send a subset of $S$ to a subset of $T$, through $G.(B,a^{-1}cB)\to  G.(B,a^{-1}cB)\cap T= B.(B,a^{-1}cB)$. It is well-defined, then it is clearly bijective.